# How to wrap-around the value when after 9 using python

Tags: python-3.x

i would like to write the program

when i input the number of 12

the program will print of digits ie.after '9' is '0'.

For example:

Enter the number: 12

output
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1

```
x = input("Enter the number: ")
x = int(x) 
for i in range (x):
    print(str(i))
```

anyone can give an idea for me? thanks

Comment: You'll find the [modulo operator (%)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) useful

Comment: Take modulo of 10.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
print(str(i))
```

To this:

```
print(i % 10)
```